# AppCenter pre-build bash script not being executed with Xamarin Forms Project

Tags: bash, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I have a Xamarin Forms application and I've been using AppCenter to build and distribute my app.

This app connects to an external API, that has QA / Dev environments. To change the API URL, I've created a pre-build script on AppCenter and put it in the root of each project (iOS / Android). In the AppCenter, it identifies the pre-build script, but it seems to not be executed (I couldn't see in the Output logs any of the Echo messages of the script).

The script is quite similar to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/blob/master/sample-build-scripts/xamarin/app-constants/appcenter-pre-build.sh), but my "AppConstant" class is inside a Helper folder in the Shared Project and I'm getting the path of this class like this: `APP_CONSTANT_FILE=$APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/Root/Root/Root/Helpers/Endpoints.cs` and I have added at the top of the script an `echo "Running pre-build bash script..."` to at least display something to make sure the script was executed, but nothing =/

The reason for adding Root/Root/Root is because of [this comment](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/124936/using-environment-variables-from-app-center-in-the-appliaction) and I have created the Environment Variable on AppCenter too.

I couldn't see any issues so far, could anybody give me a hand on that?

Comment: Please add your script here. If it does not run that mean you might have some prob in the script itself. I have it fully working on my app.

Comment: @Umar3x the script is quite the same to the one I have put a link for, the difference is instead of Root, I added the namespace of the project and the class that have the constant property has a different name.
I could figure it out by recreating the script file in a mac computer, it was something related to encoding of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could find out why the script was not being executed. It was because of the Encoding of the shell script file.

I had created the file in a Windows computer and I read that App Center runs the script in a UNIX environment (I could see some strange characters in the Output Log), so I created from scratch the file in a Mac computer and App Center started to execute.